# Python regular expression to work for dynamic match group objects

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract few interested fields from an output  using Regular expression in python.

Assuming my string as

```
Interface1 is down (Administratively down)
```

The regular expression that i have written is:

```
pat = 'Interface(\d) is (\S)+ (.*)'
```

and i was able to get the required fields but when the interface is up, there will not be reason printed and i wanted to get the regex work for that case too.. right now with the regular exp that i have written, it does not seem to work.. can someone pls help..

When the interface is up, the output would be

```
Interface1 is Up
m.group()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    m.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the space between the second and last capturing group in order to match both. Also, the `+` operator outside of the group makes it a repeating group; place it inside instead.

```
Interface(\d+) is (\S+)(.*)
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/1)

Comment: Aha! Back to demos? Cool! +1. (But you again forgot to add *#python* at the end of the URL. :( )

Comment: @BhargavRao i keep forgetting that :P

Comment: Maybe you should write a regex to automatically add that at the end! :)

Comment: Lol, why module? Add a `print("#python")` mentally at the end while you are typing out the answer :)

Comment: @BhargavRao `re.sub(r"^(.+)$",r"\1#python",link)` :P...see demo.  https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/7

Comment: Yep! That is the right way! +1 for your comment also!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because when the string is `Interface1 is Up`, your regex regex expects atleast two spaces after the substring `is`

```
>>> s1 = "Interface1 is down (Administratively down)"
>>> s2 = "Interface1 is Up"
>>> re.match(r'^Interface(\d) is (\S+)(?: (.+))?$', s1).groups()
('1', 'down', '(Administratively down)')
>>> re.match(r'^Interface(\d) is (\S+)(?: (.+))?$', s2).groups()
('1', 'Up', None)
```

In regex `(?:....)` called [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and `(...)` called [captuirng group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  `?` quantifier (which is not present just after to `+` or `*`) would turn the previous token as optional one. So `(?: (.+))` is an optional one. space inside the non-capturing group matches a single space and the `(.+)` captures all the remaining one or more characters to another group.

Comment: sorry... I;m new to regex. can you pls enlighten me on what does ?: mean here? and what essentially (?: (.+))?$', s2) does. ? sorry and pls forgive my ignorance.

Comment: the reason for why i use the above regex is, vks answer would also capture the leading space into group 3. BUt this won't. And also i added the reason for why your regex fails.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write your explanation. but one question although..While i was reading regex basics, match would always looks for pattern on the beginning of the string. if I;m correct, do we still need an '^' symbol presiding the string? i assume '^' is used for beginning of the string. kindly clarify.

Comment: it's safe to add the anchors. If all the lines are in the same format then use anchors. For example vks's regex will find a match in [`foobarbuzInterface1 is down (Administratively down)`](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/2)  where mine won't do that. `^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks..make sense but i have to be careful enough while using asserts because even a leading space / trailing space of the extract string on which regex should be operated have to be stripped... correct me if i went wrong.

Comment: if the line has leading and trailin space then use `^ *`